# How to hide banner on page change?

Tags: ionic3

I want to implement ads banner to my app. Following function displays banner but it displays on every page. How to hide banner when page change?

```
  showBanner(){
    const bannerConfig: AdMobFreeBannerConfig = {  
      isTesting: true,
      autoShow: false
     };
     this.admobFree.banner.config(bannerConfig);

     this.admobFree.banner.prepare()
       .then(() => {
         this.admobFree.banner.show();
       })
       .catch(e => console.log(e));
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ionViewWillEnter()](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/) in your [IonicPage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/) component

```
ionViewWillEnter(){
   this.admobFree.banner.hide()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Where are you executing the code to show the banner?

Use the prepare method only once. Then show and hide in whatever page you want.

In every page that you need to show the banner:

```
ionViewWillEnter(){
   this.admobFree.banner.show();
}

ionViewWillLeave(){
   this.admobFree.banner.hide();
}
```

You can take a look more in deep to the Ionic Navigating Lifecycle Events: https://blog.ionicframework.com/navigating-lifecycle-events/